# How to avoid for await...of with csv-parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, node-csv-parse, airbnb-js-styleguide

I am looking to be educated on this issue as I have spent a few days trying to resolve it on my own, to no avail.

I am using [csv-parse](https://csv.js.org/parse/) to parse a CSV file.
I am using [ESLint](https://eslint.org) as my Linter
I am using the [Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide](https://airbnb.io/javascript/) plugin for ESLint
I am running this on the backend using NodeJS

My function is:

```js
const { parse } = require('csv-parse');
const fs = require('fs');
const csvFile = 'myCsvFile.csv';

async function parseCsv(csvFile) {
  const records = [];
  const parser = fs.createReadStream(csvFile).pipe(parse({ delimiter: ',', columns: true }));
  for await (const record of parser) {
    records.push(record);
  }
  return records;
```

The function works well, however I am trying to abide by Airbnb's Style Guide, which does not like the `for await...of` loop as it is hitting me with the [`no-restricted-syntax`](https://airbnb.io/javascript/#iterators--nope) violation.

I am curious on if there is a better way to write this to fall in line with Airbnb's Style Guide or, if this is one of those situations where it's OK to ignore the violation?

Comment: Well, does any of the airbnb reasoning that you linked resonate with you?

Comment: *Why? This enforces our immutable rule. Dealing with pure functions that return values is easier to reason about than side effects.* This doesn't seem to apply to your situation.

Comment: @Bergi, great question. No, it did not resonate with me, which is why I am asking. I’m just a few years into this journey and sometimes I need help seeing the forest through the trees. What one may see as easy, I still miss.

Comment: @JeremyM Then I'd recommend not to use that style guide (or at least not that rule). Imo, airbnb is a bit misguided and often prevents you from using modern syntax.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier In a way, it actually does, `records.push(record)` is a side effect. The problem is just that currently there are no helper methods on node streams (or async iterators) that would alleviate this - however with the [*iterator helpers* proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers/) you could simplify all that to just `const records = await parser.toArray()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on advice given in the answers, I am going to ignore the [Airbnb Style Guide](https://airbnb.io/javascript/#iterators--nope) and use the [Async iterator](https://csv.js.org/parse/api/async_iterator/) method.

Final code:

```js
const { parse } = require('csv-parse');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const debug = require('debug')('app:csv:service');
const chalk = require('chalk');

async function parseCsv(csvFile) {
  try {
    const records = [];
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(csvFile);
    const parser = stream.pipe(parse({ delimiter: ',', columns: true }));
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
    for await (const record of parser) {
      records.push(record);
    }
    return records;
  } catch (error) {
    debug(`${chalk.red('Failed')} to parse CSV`);
    debug(`${chalk.red('ERROR:')} ${error}`);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

It may be time to find a new Style Guide to follow. Thank you to **num8er** for the code advice (I took one of your ideas to make my code a little more readable).

Answer (score 3):

The styleguide says:

> 11.2 Don’t use generators for now.
> Why? They don’t transpile well to ES5.

Fortunately if you're using a recent NodeJS version, you don't need to transpile down, and can use the engine's native support. For browsers this advice is also outdated soon.

Answer (score 2):

How about using events end returning promise?

```
const { parse } = require('csv-parse');
const fs = require('fs');
const csvFile = 'myCsvFile.csv';

async function parseCsv(csvFile) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const records = [];
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(csvFile);
    const parser = stream.pipe(parse({ delimiter: ',', columns: true }));
    
    parser.on('readable', () => {
      while (record = parser.read()) {
        records.push(record);
      }
    });

    let ended = false;
    const end = (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
      }

      if (!ended) {
        ended = true;
        resolve(records);
      }
    };

    parser.on('error', end);
    parser.on('end', end);
  });
}
```

also if You have node 15+ then try [stream/promises](https://csv.js.org/parse/recipes/promises/) example:

```
const { parse } = require('csv-parse');
const fs = require('fs');
const { finished } = require('stream/promises');
const csvFile = 'myCsvFile.csv';

async function parseCsv(csvFile) {
    const records = [];
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(csvFile);
    const parser = stream.pipe(parse({ delimiter: ',', columns: true }));

    parser.on('readable', () => {
      let record;
      while ((record = parser.read()) !== null) {
        records.push(record);
      }
    });

    await finished(parser);

    return records;
}
```

[image: csv-parse + stream/promises]

Comment: I'd really question the styleguide if replacing a 3 lines for loop with 20 lines of callbacks and manual promise resolution makes the code compliant ...

Comment: @JonasWilms I tried to make code not to have async/awaits, I think that's reason to make it more compatible to old lts stuff :)

Comment: I was able to make it work as a Promise but I agree with @Jonas Wilms, it took a lot more code to make it work. I’m starting to question the Style Guide. This will shake my world though . I started this journey 3 years ago forcing myself to learn following the Airbnb style guide. It’s almost a religion for me.

Comment: @JeremyM You can use `on_record` and simplify my code, https://csv.js.org/parse/options/on_record/

Comment: @JeremyM if You're using node 15+, then please check example with stream/promises, I've updated my answer

Comment: @num8er It works well, except `while (record = parser.read())` triggers [no-cond-assign](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-cond-assign).  Can't win with ESLint.

Comment: @JeremyM updated my answer, please check